# RequireJs Optimization on Windows fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

Trying to optimize an requirejs-based project on Windows. Have put the r.js.cmd in the Scripts folder along with the following nodeBuild.js file.

```
({
baseUrl: ".",
paths: {
    jquery: "empty:"
},
name: "main",
out: "main-built.js"
})
```

When using the command

```
node r.js.cmd -o nodeBuild.js
```

I get the following response:

```
r.js.cmd:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @IF EXIST "%~dp0
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

Tried searching for it but can't find similar error description and since it is windows I use the r.js.cmd instead of the r.js. The requirejs main.js file is in the Scripts folder and all other modules is in subdirectories to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't run it through node.

```
r.js.cmd -o nodeBuild.js
```

Comment: Running this commande without node first gives me the following error referencing the folder above the Scripts-folder that I'm executing the command in: Cannot find module 'D:\Projects\SampleProject\requirejs\bin\r.js'.

Comment: Putting the r.js file into a driectory structure like it wants just brings me the same error as if I would execute the r.js directly: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on basedir='dirname "$"', and the pointer is on the first '.

Comment: @Hyzac Just install it via npm: `npm install requirejs -g`; don't put it in your project folder.

Comment: ok, seems like the global installation of requirejs hadn't worked previous so first I got it working by navigating to the locally installed node_modules/.bin folder and executing r.js.cmd. When retrying the global install and executing it from the root it worked aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#download) it seems to me that the equivalent of a *nix:

```
r.js -o nodeBuild.js
```

would be on Windows:

```
r.js.cmd -o nodeBuild.js
```

That is, don't pass it to Node but let Windows run it. `r.js.cmd` is a Windows command file, which Node cannot interpret. When you do it like you've shown in your question, Node tries to interpret that file and fails.